# How can I update HP iLO 4 Card firmware without a web interface

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I have a HP ProLiant DL580 Gen 8 Server with an iLO Card giving me an "Error 270 - Unable to communicate with iLO firmware". So I am attempting to connect to the iLO port to upgrade/reflash the firmware but am having trouble connecting since the card does not give me a web interface or show up in Linux. Is there some way to connect to the iLO Card without an IP Address or even reflash the card without connecting at all?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Edit:
The output of `lsmod | grep ipmi` is:

```
ipmi_si                59965  0  
ipmi_devintf           17459  0  
ipmi_msghandler        56728  2 ipmi_devintf,ipmi_si
```

The output of `ipmi` in `dmesg` is:

```
[   22.664142] ipmi_si: IPMI System Interface driver  
[   22.667628] ipmi_si dmi-ipmi-si.0: probing via SMBIOS  
[   22.668668] ipmi_platform: ipmi_si: SMBIOS: io 0xca2 regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 0
[   22.668675] ipmi_si: Adding SMBIOS-specified kcs state machine  
[   22.675631] ipmi_si IPI0001:00: probing via ACPI  
[   22.679063] ipmi_si IPI0001:00: [io  0x0ca2-0x0ca3] regsize 1 spacing 1 irq 0  
[   22.679593] ipmi_si dmi-ipmi-si.0: Removing SMBIOS-specified kcs state machine in favor of ACPI  
[   22.737049] ipmi_si: Adding ACPI-specified kcs state machine  
[   22.757657] ipmi_si: Trying ACPI-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x20, irq 0  
[   22.757669] ipmi_si IPI0001:00: Interface detection failed
```

Edit:
The output of running the command `dmesg | grep hpilo` is as follows:

```
[geek@geekserver ~]$ dmesg | grep hpilo
[   87.717656] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.727853] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.739278] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.750622] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.762020] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.772910] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.783734] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.796155] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.806400] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.818259] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.829745] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.841088] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.851992] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.863278] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.875723] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[   87.886720] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.896935] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.907968] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.918400] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.928718] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.939963] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.951204] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.961535] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.971841] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.982877] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  117.993143] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  118.004062] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  118.014426] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  118.024998] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  118.036891] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  118.047279] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  118.057745] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.068697] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.080446] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.090693] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.101694] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.111935] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.122970] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.133202] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.144305] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.154549] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.166109] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.177431] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.188509] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.200271] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.210513] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.220775] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  148.231031] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.843807] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.855360] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.866443] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.878822] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.891445] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.901802] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.912156] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.923296] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.933581] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.944703] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.955724] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.966785] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.978467] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  170.990357] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  171.000659] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  171.011671] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.024190] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.034618] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.045038] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.055421] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.065722] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.077786] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.088093] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.098369] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.108609] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.119653] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.129894] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.141077] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.151289] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.162286] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.172489] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  201.183520] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.194412] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.205426] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.215671] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.225926] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.236885] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.247999] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.258969] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.269165] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.280608] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.290806] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.301702] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.311896] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.323642] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.333849] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.344792] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
[  231.355017] hpilo 0000:01:00.2: Open could not dequeue a packet
```

Comment: What exactly means "does not show up in Linux"? How you expected to see it? Do you have `ipmi_devintf` and other IPMI modules loaded, what they are saying in `dmesg`?

Comment: It means I cannot interact with the ilo card through tools like hponcfg, because the driver doesn't load.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I have edited the question to include the additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance I managed to fix it.

The way I did was to reflash the firmware through the iLO ports FTP service.

Anyone interested do the following:

1. Grab the iLO firmware .exe file from: (Be sure to get the right file for your iLO version) https://support.hpe.com/connect/s/softwaredetails?softwareId=MTX_ad5c5b7896424a6e8a110ef7cf
2. Extract the .bin file it by following the "Obtaining the iLO firmware image file" instructions found here: https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docLocale=en_US&docId=sf000046896en_us
3. Using FTP transfer the file to the server, by following: look for the "iLO network Failed Flash Recovery" section (page 355) in the iLO 4 User Guide https://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/377263a.pdf

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. This will stop this question from floating around as unanswered, and also help those who have the same issue to find a solution faster.

Answer (score 0):

Download the `hponcfg` utility for Linux.

You can use the tool to interact with the ILO, program the ILO, and reset/reboot the ILO processor.

```
# hponcfg
HPE Lights-Out Online Configuration utility
Version 5.6.0 Date 11/30/2020 (c) 2005,2020 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP
Firmware Revision = 2.79 Device type = iLO 4 Driver name = hpilo

USAGE:
  hponcfg  -?
  hponcfg  -h
  hponcfg  -m minFw
  hponcfg  -r [-m minFw]
  hponcfg  -b [-m minFw]
  hponcfg  [-a] -w filename [-m minFw]
  hponcfg  -g [-m minFw]
  hponcfg  -f filename [-l filename] [-s namevaluepair] [-v] [-m minFw] [-u username] [-p password]
  hponcfg  -i [-l filename] [-s namevaluepair] [-v] [-m minFw] [-u username] [-p password]

  -h,  --help           Display this message
  -?                    Display this message
  -r,  --reset          Reset the Management Processor to factory defaults
  -b,  --reboot         Reboot Management Processor without changing any setting
  -f,  --file           Get/Set Management Processor configuration from "filename"
  -i,  --input          Get/Set Management Processor configuration from the XML input
                        received through the standard input stream.
  -w,  --writeconfig    Write the Management Processor configuration to "filename"
  -a,  --all            Capture complete Management Processor configuration to the file.
                        This should be used along with '-w' option
  -l,  --log            Log replies to "filename"
  -v,  --xmlverbose     Display all the responses from Management Processor
  -s,  --substitute     Substitute variables present in input config file
                        with values specified in "namevaluepairs"
  -g,  --get_hostinfo   Get the Host information
  -m,  --minfwlevel     Minimum firmware level
  -u,  --username       iLO Username
  -p,  --password       iLO Password
```

Comment: I have downloaded and installed hponcfg. it returns the following when I execute it: ```ERROR: CpqCiCreateFunc() 1 time failed. 
Driver Error Code:(1,1h).
Driver Error Message: CPQCIDRV driver is not loaded.
ERROR: A general system error occurred while detecting Management Processor. 
ACTION REQUIRED: Check if iLO and iLO driver are up and running.
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Currently to interact with the system I am using CentOS 7. I have tried installing Windows Server 2012 R2 but it gets stuck on the windows loading screen.

Comment: You'll need the following packages:  "hp-snmp-agents", "hpssa", "hp-health", "hp-smh-templates", "hpsmh", "hpssacli", "hponcfg"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have installed the entire Management Component Pack (MCP) via [link](https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/project/mcp/) and still get that message.

Comment: Remove power from the server. Unplug the PSUs. Reapply power to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I found a way to fix it.